# How to alert if the string is found

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I need Greasemonkey to check a site, and show an alert if 2 strings are found.

If site contains 'DUCK' and 'GEESE', alert with 'FOUND IT'

After extensive research online, I've found many examples, none of which seem to work.

Please help, I'm not sure where to turn next!

All versions I've tried so far:

```
function highlightWord(word) {
    var xpath = "//text()[contains(., '" + word + "')]";
    var texts = document.evaluate(xpath, document.body, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (n = 0; n < texts.snapshotLength; n++) {
        var textNode = texts.snapshotItem(n);
        var p = textNode.parentNode;
        var a = [];
        var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        textNode.nodeValue.split(word).forEach(function(text, i) {
            var node;
            if (i) {
                alert("FOUND IT");            }
            return a;
        });
        p.replaceChild(frag, textNode);
    }
}
highlightWord('DUCKS');
highlightWord('GEESE');
```

```
if(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("DUCKS") == -1){
  alert("FOUND IT");
}
```

```
if (/DUCKS/i.test (document.body.innerHTML) )
{
    alert ("FOUND IT");
}
```

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'DUCKS')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var node=xpathResult.singleNodeValue;
if (node==null)
    alert("NOT FOUND IT");
else
    alert("FOUND IT");
```

```
function findAndAlert(element){
  var foundDUCKS = false,
      foundGEESE = false;

  if (element.match(/DUCKS/i) foundDUCKS = true;
  if (element.match(/GEESE/i) foundGEESE = true;

  if (foundDUCKS && foundGEESE) alert('FOUND BOTH');
  else if (foundDUCKS && !foundGEESE) alert('FOUND ONE');
}

findAndAlert(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/map_final.php") {
   if (/DUCKS/i.test (document.getElementById('res').innerHTML)){
     if(confirm("FOUND IT")) { clearInterval(interval); }
   }
}, 1000);
}

document.getElementById('res').innerHTML)
```

So far it's either not alerting, or alerting even if the text isn't present

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a boolean if the text is present in the DOM:

```js
// Case insensitive. 
function findText(text){
  return document.querySelector('body').textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
}
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I had some time on my hands so I made an interactive example using the previous authors code for search.  You can access it here: https://github.com/EGREllis/Javascript/blob/master/index.html